# Could wrap content vs fill parent affect which text size should be applied when using the built in textAppearanceLarge

Tags: android, textview

So I have one screen that is mostly defined in XML, and I had chosen ?attr/textAppeareanceLarge in the XML file.

When I put some code to find the `TextView` ID, dump the textsize to LogCat, change the text appearance using `setTextAppearance` to `android.R.attr.textAppearnaceSmall`, the size remains unchanged. Log says it's using 33.0 textsize

Conversely, in a custom preference that I was tinkering with, I wanted to create a text label. Programmatically specifying the text to be large using `setTextAppearance(android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge)` still yield small text size (at the 20 something ballpark).

The only think that I could think of as to why the text size is screwed up is that one I might have used fill parent, and the other, wrap content. Could it really affect the text size?

Update: perhaps some code would better demonstrate. I'm creating a custom preference widget. It should have a text label that uses the text string for the preference title, and a time picker. What i'm not getting is that why is the textAppearanceLarge here doesn't change the text size. i.e. the log before the setTextAppearance and after returns the same value.

```
@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    params1.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    params1.weight = 1.0f;

    TextView text = new TextView(getContext());
    text.setText(getTitle());
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),Float.toString(text.getTextSize()));
    text.setTextAppearance(getContext(),android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge);
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),Float.toString(text.getTextSize()));
    text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    text.setLayoutParams(params1);

    TimePicker picker = new TimePicker(getContext());
    picker.setCurrentHour(m_hour);
    picker.setCurrentMinute(m_minute);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params2.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

    picker.setLayoutParams(params2);
    picker.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);
    picker.setLayoutParams(params2);

    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    layout.addView(text);
    layout.addView(picker);
    layout.setId(android.R.id.widget_frame);

    return layout;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LOL. I've been scratching my head for days, and searching about this issue for quite some time, and right when I edit this question, I find the answer in the android issue tracker.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1727

I should be doing:

```
text.setTextAppearance(getContext(),android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
```